# When can I initialize a view inside a fragment, that is being created by my current fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

**Solved**

I have a `fragment` that pops up as soon as my application starts. i.e. `HomeFragment`

In this `HomeFragment` I have a bunch of views like buttons and `textviews` but also a `Tablayout`(3 tabs) with a `viewPager`. My `viewPager` loads, depending on which tab is currently selected, different other fragments (A, B or C).

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {
...
...

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    btnMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
    btnMenu.setOnClickListener(this);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new AFragment(), "", getContext());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new BFragment(), "", getContext());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new CFragment(), "", getContext());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


  //  initializeItems();

      return view;
}
```

So far so good.
Now, inside my `AFragment` is a `RecyclerView`.

In order to fill this `RecyclerView` with data I'm calling a method called `initializeItems()`.

```
 public void initializeEventItems() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    ...
    //some other stuff
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The question is, in which method can I call this `initializeItems()` method?

If I call it at the end of my `onCreateView` method I'm getting a `NullObjectReference : recyclerView is Null`

If I call it for example in my `onClick` method for my ImageButton it works.

I already tried to call it from the `onViewCreated` method. But that didn't work either.

**Edit:**

Piyush helped me finding the problem. I tried to initialize a view from another fragment.

Comment: Passed view object in `initializeEventItems(View view)` then try to `recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);` It will work.

Comment: my question is why you are initializing recyclerView and adapter in home fragment, actually your recyclerView is in AFragment so you should do this in AFragment's onCreateView()

Comment: If you initialize in `onCreateView()` then it should be _recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);_

Comment: AnkitaShah: Still NullPointerException     Shrenik Shah:    I will try that       Piyush: So this is basically the same Ankita wanted me to do.

Comment: AnkitaShah: Still NullPointerException     Shrenik Shah:    I will try that       Piyush: So this is basically the same Ankita wanted me to do.

Comment: But in oncreateView method did u inflate your custom view and return that view? I want to see your updated code for onCreateView

Comment: What do you mean by custom view? I inflated my home_fragment layout as you can see in the code above. All I changed: initializeEventItems(view);  instead of initializeEventItems();

Comment: Then make sure that in  if initializeItems(); in onCreateView() then this will be 
   _recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);_ Make sure also that recycler view is in _fragment_home_ file

Comment: Something's wrong with your first sentence, or am I wrong? If guess u were trying to say that I need to adjust my initialization to  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);  Yes I did that. There is no recycler view in my fragment_home.xml. As I said, my fragment_home contains the ViewPager and the TabLayout. My Recycler View is inside fragment_A.xml that is being displayed in my ViewPager (if first tab of TabLayout is selected)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124887/discussion-between-piyush-and-sara-lince).